# Determine all integers (bigger than 1) such that $\frac{2^n+1}{n^2}$ is an integer

Tags: calculus, modular-arithmetic, logarithms, contest-math

> Determine all integers $k>1$ such that $$ \dfrac{2^k+1}{k^2}\in\mathbb{N}$$

I have tried to solve for even numbers $(k=2n)$ and for odd numbers $(k=2n+1)$, but i couldn't find any answer to this.
I think i have to begin by saying that $$2^k+1\equiv 0 \pmod{k^2} $$ but i don't know how to continue.

Comment: Hint: Here you can find an answer
https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h60740p366466

Comment: Just for reference, this is problem 3 from [IMO 1990](https://www.imo-official.org/year_info.aspx?year=1990).